# Changing the id for two users in one statement

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

```
+----+----------------------+----------+-----------+
| id | fullname             | username | password  |
+----+----------------------+----------+-----------|
|  1 | John Doe             | jdoe     | pass      |
|  2 | Bob Doe              | bdoe     | pass      |  
+----+----------------------+----------+-----------+
```

Essentially what I want to do is 'flip' the ID's for both users in the same query, to avoid key overlap (the id is the primary key).

So I want it to look like this:

```
+----+----------------------+----------+-----------+
| id | fullname             | username | password  |
+----+----------------------+----------+-----------|
|  1 | Bob Doe              | bdoe     | pass      |
|  2 | John Doe             | jdoe     | pass      |  
+----+----------------------+----------+-----------+
```

I've tried the following, but they did not work:

```
UPDATE users SET id=1 WHERE id=2, id=2 WHERE id=1;
UPDATE users SET id=CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 2 WHEN 2 THEN 1 END WHERE id IN (1,2);
```

They produced these errors, respectively:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Sorry for the newbie question. I'm still a beginner at MySQL.

Comment: That second form should work in standard SQL. Guessing there's some mysqlism that makes it not do so.

Comment: Generally, when swapping a and b, move b to c, a to b, and then b to a, but why swap?

Comment: Can't really do it. Even though the update itself is atomic, there will be internally a brief moment when ONE of the records will be changed to share the ID of the OTHER record, leading to the duplicate key problem.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't believe you!

Comment: Why not swap contents? Swapping ID will almost always fail if the steps are in series which they always are.

Comment: @Strawberry - Basically, all of the updates should be processed "as if" they all happen in parallel - all rows should magically transform from their old state to their new state - in the same way that you should be able to swap two columns contents by doing `UPDATE t SET a=b,b=a` without having to use any intermediate storage.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever And standard sql supports that behaviour on a PK?

Comment: The first form doesn't work in MySQL at all.

Comment: @Strawberry - certainly works on [SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79c6f/1) and I believe that it's hewing closer to the standard than mysql is here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following hack, but it is really a hack and not recommended for any serious purpose:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE USERS SET id=0 WHERE id=1;
UPDATE USERS SET id=1 WHERE id=2;
UPDATE USERS SET id=2 where id=0;
COMMIT;
```